# quote/escape output from local builtin to pass back to itself with builtins only?

Tags: bash, escaping, quoting, subshell

**Edit:** Mostly rewritten for clarity/digestibility. Also, I found one possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032793/307542) using xargs. I prefer avoiding the external command--I'll only accept my own answer if no alternative turns up.

I'm trying to pass the output of `local` (declared local variables as a newline-delimited `key=value` list), back to another invocation of local, but I'm bumping up against the edge of my understanding of bash quoting/escaping.

It's easy to handle values with no spaces, but values with internal spaces cause quoting/splitting trouble. Easier to show than tell. Using `BASH_VERSION=4.4.23(1)-release`. I'll walk through the steps; there's a longer repro script at the end of the post.

1. Define some local variables, and print them with the `local` builtin:

   ```sh
   function export_locals(){
       local one=1
       local two=$(echo word1 word2)
       local three=$(echo "word1 ain't word2")
       local # aka local -p
   }
   ```

   Which outputs some variation of:

   ```
   one=1
   three='word1 ain'\''t word2'
   two='word1 word2'
   ```
2. Call `export_locals` from another function, and pass the output to another invocation of the `local` builtin:

   ```
   function import_locals(){
       local $(export_locals)
       local
   }
   ```

   With the default `IFS`, this will fail. `set -x` shows the cause:

   ```
   + local one=1 'three='\''word1' 'ain'\''\'\'''\''t' 'word2'\''' 'two='\''word1' 'word2'\'''
   bash: local: `ain'\''t': not a valid identifier
   bash: local: `word2'': not a valid identifier
   bash: local: `word2'': not a valid identifier
   ```

   Using `IFS=$'\n'` keeps it from splitting the values of `two` or `three`, but they end up with bonus single quotes:

   ```
   + local one=1 'three='\''word1 ain'\''\'\'''\''t word2'\''' 'two='\''word1 word2'\'''
   + local
   one=1
   three=''\''word1 ain'\''\'\'''\''t word2'\'''
   two=''\''word1 word2'\'''
   ```

   At this point `echo $two` would output `'word1 word2'`

I'm looking for ways to remove the spare quotes that won't break the field splitting, won't break on more complex inputs like `$three`, and ideally don't rely on external commands. I also prefer not screwing with the IFS, but I don't think that's in the cards.

Reproduction script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

# declare 2 vars and export them
function export_locals(){
    local one=1
    local two=$(echo word1 word2)
    local three=$(echo "word1 ain't word2")
    local # aka local -p
}

# insert vars into different local namespace
function import_locals(){
    echo ${one:-nah} ${two:-nope} # nothing up my sleeve
    local $(export_locals)
    local
    echo ${one:-nah} ${two:-nope} ${three:-nope}
}

function test_export_import_locals(){
    export_locals # just to show what it prints
    import_locals # bad attempt
    IFS=$'\n' import_locals # good (ish?) attempt
}
```

Comment: Don't try to pass around shell syntax in variables or or function output; the shell expands things like `$var` and `$(command)` partway through the parsing process, so the results get sort of weirdly half-parsed. Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, there's almost certain to be a better way to do it. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm leaving the original answer below unchanged, but the underlying behavior changes in bash 5.1, where the output of `local` now behaves more like other setters.*

---

I eventually iterated into a tolerable solution with external command xargs, which I've supplied below.

```sh
function import_locals(){
    local $(export_locals_xargs)
    local
}
function export_locals_xargs(){
    local one=1
    local two=$(echo word1 word2)
    local three=$(echo "word1 ain't word2")
    local | xargs printf "%s\n"
}
IFS=$'\n' import_locals
```

This will output:

```
one=1
three='word1 ain'\''t word2'
two='word1 word2'
```

Echoing the individual variables outputs:

```
one: 1
two: word1 word2
three: word1 ain't word2
```

---

**bash 5.1+**

```sh
function import_locals(){
    eval "$(export_locals_xargs)"
    local
}
function export_locals_xargs(){
    local one=1
    local two=$(echo word1 word2)
    local three=$(echo "word1 ain't word2")
    local -p
}
import_locals
```

This outputs:

```
declare -- one="1"
declare -- three="word1 ain't word2"
declare -- two="word1 word2"
```